# How to connect to sql database through php/pdo that has been exported from mysql/phpmyadmin as mydatabase.sql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have searched on many different sites and cannot find an answer that specifically answers this question:

I have WAMP Server installed, which installed phpmyadmin as well as MySQL. I can easily connect to the database through php/pdo by using localhost as my hostname.

But my problem is I am trying to connect to a database that I have exported from phpmyadmin as "mydatabase.sql". So now lets say I placed this file on my pc at "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MyFolder\mydatabase.sql". How would I connect to this database (if this is possible)?

The reason is that I cannot install WAMP Server on all the pcs that would use this program. so would like to be able to connect to the database without having to install any type of servers, etc...

My php at the moment is:

```
<?php
$dsn='mysql:C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MyFolder\mydatabase.sql';
$username='username';
$password='pass';

try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("$dsn",$username,$password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        echo $row["ID"] ." - ". $row["Name"] ."<br/>";
    }

    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Also, if this is possible, would username and password be necessary to connect to an "off server database"?

If I try:

```
$dsn='sqlite:C:\Users\Optique\Desktop\optique.sql';
```

I get:
"Connected to Database
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 26 file is encrypted or is not a database"

But I think that is because SQLite uses a different database format than MySQL (stand to be corrected). So what I need is something similar to the SQLite driver for MySQL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find an answer simply because it doesn't exist: it's **impossible** to connect to an SQL dump through PDO, and it makes no sense anyway: a dump is not a database but simply a collection of INSERT queries. Unlike sqlite, for mysql you need a server to connect with.

To be able to connect, you should import that dump into mysql database first and then connect to that database with PDO.

Comment: So if this database was situated on another pc instead of the one I created it on and am testing it on, I would need to install WAMP, or whatever on that pc? I am desperately trying to avoid that, as I cannot install any type of database server software on the pc where I would eventually like the database to reside.

Comment: Thanks. Those weren't my exact words quoted but okay. Accepted as answer as "Either use sqlite instead of mysql or you will have to install MySQL" helped me a lot. I converted my sql dump into SQLite db file and connected exactly as I wanted.

Comment: @RAlexander Often this scenario would involve a database server, one master server running the database, and the client machines would connect to that server by network connection to manipulate the data. That's sort of the beauty of a database server; the server is designed to deal with many clients at once and you can keep all your data in sync through many clients.

Comment: @Isaac thank you. I understand that yes and I understand the benefits of a database server and all of that as I have worked with them before. In this specific case however, I needed a database file much like a Microsoft access file. I just needed it in a SQL format instead of mdb. Which mysql does not offer. So.i ended up using sqlite which I don't like at all by the way. But atleast this gives me close to what I wanted.